# PHP: identical mysql_fetch_array statements working in one place but not in another

Tags: php, html, mysql, textarea, echo

I've made a page where users can upload statuses, which are then displayed in a readonly textarea. My problem is, I want to display the time the status was uploaded in a textarea underneath the one displaying the status, but this is not working. I can display whatever I want in the first textarea (including the status upload time, using the same ['time_posted'] tag), but nothing will show up in the second textarea, even if I copypaste the first textarea integrally. I have no idea what's causing this and can't see where I could have possibly gone wrong, so I'd really appreciate some feedback as to what the problem might be.

PS: I know mysql is (in the process of being) deprecated, so don't bother telling me about mysqli and PDO. I'll eventually replace all of the relevant code.

```
  <textarea readonly style="position:absolute; top:54%; left:45.2%;
  border-style: none; border-color: Transparent; overflow: auto; resize:none;"
  cols="16" rows="3"><?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($showstatus)) 
  {echo $row['status'] . " ";}?></textarea>

  <textarea readonly style="position:absolute; top:63%; left:45.2%;
  border-style: none; border-color: Transparent; overflow: auto; resize:none;"
  cols="16" rows="3"><?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($showstatus)) 
  {echo $row['time_posted'] . " ";}?></textarea>
```

Comment: `I'll eventually replace all of the relevant code. `: rather, I'll eventually `be forced to` replace all of the relevant code.

Comment: haha, I know, but it's a pretty compact project so this won't be too big of a deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it before but you can reset your mysql data pointer with `mysql_data_seek(0)`. Thinking about it this would probably use slightly less memory than storing it in an array, but it probably holds database connections unnecessearily long.

**[Reference:](https://www.php.net/mysql_data_seek)**

Comment: That's a very good answer. If I had asked the question, I would accept this answer.

Comment: Excellent, yes, got it to work using mysql_data_seek($showstatus, 0);the rest of the code. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

The second one does not print because after your first loop the pointer has reached the end of values and there are no more values to fetch

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($showstatus))
```

After it is complete, you cannot fetch more values from the same object like that because you have already reached the end of records.

**Solution:**

Ether fetch the result again, or create a new array in your first loop and then iterate over that array for your second loop.

Example

Create a new array in your first loop like  `$values=$row[]`. Like

**First loop**

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($showstatus)){echo $row['status'] . " "; $values[]=$row;}?>
```

Then change your second loop to

```
 foreach($values as $row)
```

Like

```
<?php foreach($values as $row){echo $row['time_posted'] . " ";}?>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response! is there a way I could 'reset' the loop to do the same thing for the second textarea?

Comment: See the answer by @jdog, that's much better than mine.

Comment: hah, sorry, couldn't keep up with the pace of the comments. Thanks man. It is thanks to your comment that I conceptually understand what's going wrong, so if I were able to, I'd upvote you as well.